# How to export a PDF from an endpoint in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf, django-rest-framework

I'm currently setting up a **GET** request from my endpoint to export a PDF file based on the filters(**django_filters**) on my ModelViewSet and the PDF's design will based on the template_path provided. And I'm fairly new on using DRF, so I'm new to some things.

I've tried using **easy_pdf** for my ModelViewSet, but it doesn't show on the endpoint's **GET** request. And also no error was provided in the logs, I assume I'm doing something really wrong on this.

This is my Filter

```
class CarrierFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_app_rec__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_app_rec', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_app_rec__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_app_rec', lookup_expr='lte')
    date_sample_rec__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_sample_rec', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_sample_rec__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_sample_rec', lookup_expr='lte')
    date_of_qca__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_of_qca', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_of_qca__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_of_qca', lookup_expr='lte')
    date_created__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_created', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_created__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_created', lookup_expr='lte')
    patient_name = CharFilter(field_name='patient_name', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Carrier
        fields = ('date_app_rec__gte', 'date_app_rec__lte', 
                'date_sample_rec__gte', 'date_sample_rec__lte',
                  'date_of_qca__gte', 'date_of_qca__lte',
                  'date_created__gte', 'date_created__lte',
                  'patient_name',)
```

And this is my ModelViewSet

```
class CarrierViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, PDFTemplateResponseMixin, ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CarrierSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    filename = 'carrier-reports.xlsx'
    pdf_filename = 'carrier-report.pdf'
    filter_class = (CarrierFilter)
    filterset_fields = ('patient_name', 'promo_code')
    search_fields = ('patient_name', 'promo_code', 'insurance_verified_tsg_verification')

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        position = self.request.user.position
        if position == 'Manager':
            queryset = Carrier.objects.filter(manager__name=user)
        else:
            queryset = Carrier.objects.filter(agent__name=user)
        return queryset

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        carrier = Carrier.objects.all()
        template_path = 'carrier/carrier_print.html'
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="carrier-report.pdf"'

        html = render_to_string(template_path, {'carrier': carrier})
        print(html)

        pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response)

        return response
```

What I want to do is that the pdf should be in the **GET** request of that endpoint, same scenario as the drf_renderer_xlsx when using the xlsx from the **GET**. Or is there another way around on doing this?